# Out of space when opening Realm database

Tags: android, realm

My Android emulator has run out of space on its internal storage, due to other files. When I call `Realm.getInstance(config)` *at app startup* the following exception is being thrown:

```
io.realm.exceptions.RealmError: Unrecoverable error. write(): failed: No space left on device in /home/cc/repo/realm/release/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_SharedRealm.cpp line 217
                                                                                                at io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.nativeGetSharedRealm(Native Method)
                                                                                                at io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.<init>(SharedRealm.java:190)
                                                                                                at io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.getInstance(SharedRealm.java:237)
                                                                                                at io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.getInstance(SharedRealm.java:206)
                                                                                                at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:127)
                                                                                                at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:284)
```

I am confused by this because the database has already been successfully written before space ran out. I simply want to open and read from the database - no writes required. In fact, it's a requirement of my app to be able to read from the database in all conditions if it's present.

Obviously since this is at app startup I haven't leaked any Realm instances and there are no outstanding transactions. What is going on?

Comment: I assume Realm needs some specific number for the memory mapping it's doing.

Comment: Are you using `compactOnLaunch`? At worst that will require the same amount of free space as the current size of the file as compacting are not don in place but by copying data to another file

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a new AVD with a larger storage size for the sdcard.

Comment: I'm looking for an overall solution, as I'd like to be able to open a Realm database even with no storage available.